# Build and bind against older libc version

Tags: rust, libc

I have dependencies in my code that requires libc. When building (`cargo build --release`) on Ubuntu 20.04 (glibc 2.31) the resulting executable doesn't run on CentOS 7 (glibc 2.17). It throws an error saying it requires GLIBC 2.18.

When build the same code on CentOS 7 the resulting executable runs on CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Is there a way to control which GLIBC version is required to build this version on Ubuntu 20.04 too?

Comment: It is not easy. You can try something like "build-anywhere" https://github.com/theopolis/build-anywhere (not my code).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your project does not depend on any native libraries, then probably the easiest way would be to use the `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` target.

This target statically links against [MUSL Libc](https://musl.libc.org/) rather than dynamically linking against the system's libc. As a result it produces completely static binaries which should run on a wide range of systems.

To install this target:

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

To build your project using this target:

```
cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

See [the edition guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/platform-and-target-support/musl-support-for-fully-static-binaries.html) for more details.

If you are using any non-rust libraries it becomes more difficult, because they may be dynamically linked and may in turn depend on the system libc. In that case you would either need to statically link the external libraries (assuming that is even possible, and that the libraries you are using will work with MUSL libc), or make different builds for each platform you want to target.

If you end up having to make different builds for each platform, a docker container would be the easiest way to achieve that.

Comment: I'd say this answer is missing essential commands to be used but it leads to the solution. It worked for me.

Comment: @Todd this answer is about statically linking to MUSL, which is [MIT licenced](https://musl.libc.org/about.html). MUSL is not GLIBC.

Comment: @harmic Oh - is MUSL Libc different? That's news to me. I'll have to look into it!

Comment: @Kind Contributor in my (limited) experience it is. I have few projects (small apps, I'm still learning rust) and in some of them I've noticed that they work and compile with no problems using the standard target but with MUSL they don't compile or the resulting binary gives segfaults. Maybe I was just unlucky however to me it looks like MUSL has too much differences at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

Try `cross`.

Install it globally:

`cargo install cross`

Then build your project with it:

`cross build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --release`

`cross` take the same arguments as `cargo` but you have to specify a target explicitly. Also, the build directory is always `target/{TARGET}/(debug|release)`, not `target/(debug|release)`

`cross` uses docker images prebuilt for different target architectures but nothing stops you from "cross-compiling" against the host architecture. The glibc version in these docker images should be conservative enough. If it isn't, you can always configure `cross` to use a custom image.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to build binaries for a given OS on that OS, or at the very least build on the oldest OS you intend to support.

glibc uses symbol versioning to preserve the behavior of older programs while adding support for new functionality.  For example, a newer version of `pthread_mutex_lock` may support lock elision, while the old one would not.  You're seeing this error because when you link against libc, you link against the default version of the symbol if a version isn't explicitly specified, and in at least one case, the version you linked against is from glibc 2.18.  Changing this would require recompiling libstd (and the libc crate, if you're using it) with custom changes to pick the old versioned symbols, which is a lot of work for little gain.

If your only dependency is glibc, then it might be sufficient to just compile on CentOS 7.  However, if you depend on other libraries, like OpenSSL, then those just aren't compatible across OS versions because their SONAMEs differ, and there's no way around that.  So that's why generally you want to build different binaries per OS.

Comment: Interresting. I thought rust builds are independent of system libraries. And it's not my dependency. A simple hello world app still needs the same libc. OK, than I have to build on an older OS or use build-anywhere mentioned by Andrey.

Comment: On most OSes, Rust still uses the standard C facilities (libc, pthreads, etc.), and can interoperate with C libraries if you choose to use them.